# Coredata, EXC_BAD_ACCESS or weird behaviour on related objects

Tags: cocoa, core-data, memory-management

I have a Journal NSManagedObject subclass which has many Pages.
I have created this custom method (in a category) to get an array of the pages in their order.
As you see it's quite straightforward.

```
//
// @returns an array of pages sorted by indexInJournal
//
- (NSArray*)sortedPages {
    NSLog(@"Are we in main thread? %i", [NSThread isMainThread]);
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"indexInJournal"
                                                               ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    NSArray *result = [[self.pages allObjects] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    return result;
}
```

For some reason the method fails sometimes, and I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the `self` object; which is strange, since I am executing the method on it. NSZombieEnabled hasn't helped.

When called from other routines, the method works but just returns a single page (the first one); I am sure there are 3 pages.

Is there something I am missing on the way coredata istantiates/releases objects?

Cheers,
Davide

Comment: Does your pages relationship involve the cascade deletion rule? If so, make sure none of the pages returns YES to isDeleted before feeding them to the sortedPages/Array method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was.
Basically, when creating pages, I was adding them to the journal pages set and the releasing them; and thus I learned you don't release a NSManagedObject. 
This is what generated EXC_BAD_ACCESS. It was a bit tricky to detect because pages get created automatically when necessary, so I wasn't aware I was adding them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure you are on the same thread as the `Journal` object's managedObjectContext or the `Journal` object may not be able to find the `Pages` objects in the relationship.

Crossing threads causes all kinds of problems. Verify that the methods work on a single thread before getting fancy.